# Who was Tony talking to in the post-credits scene?

Tags: marvel, iron-man-3, marvel-cinematic-universe

I went to see Iron Man 3 with my family recently.

Like all Marvel movies, it has a post-credit scene.  In Iron Man 3, this scene is particularly funny.

Unfortunately, my children were acting up - they got extremely bored during the credits.  I wasn't able to watch the screen closely during the scene, and I didn't recognize the other actor by face or voice.

Who was the other character Tony was talking to?

My suspicion is that it was

> Dr. Bruce Banner

but I may well be wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it was the person in your spoiler.  The post-credits scene suggests the entire film was Tony sitting down with

> Dr. Bruce Banner (AKA The Hulk), played by Mark Ruffalo,

and recounting the events.  This means Tony's narration is explained in-universe as him adding details to the story as he's telling it.